# Errors while using Sqlite-net on Xamarin studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I am using sqlite-net in Xamarin Studio for Xamarin.forms application. In that I have put the sqlite-net library version 1.0.8. I have created the interface which I would be implementing in the platforms. But when I try to compile the PCL project I am getting a lot of errors which are present in the SQLite.cs file which was added when I added the PCL for sqlite-net.

I initially thought that the file is not important but it started giving more errors in the application. How to resolve this issue?

I am using a video tutorial for which used Visual studio for making the sample.
I am attaching the pic for the same. I would like to mention that the problem is not in my file the compile time errors are in the library.

[image]

EDIT: The PCL version of the package is 1.0.8
I had added the file in the application with content

```cs
using System;
using SQLite;

namespace SQLiteExample
{
    public interface ISQLite
    {
        SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably should use Visual Studio for Mac to avoid any legacy tooling which might have an impact.

Comment: I face the same problem in using Visual Studio for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [SQLite-Net-PCL](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL) instead of [SQLite-Net](https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net).

Comment: I used the PCL by Frank Krueger
https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/ . This is mentioned to be used by the  official document of Xamarin .
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

Comment: Do you use Xamarin studio or Visual Studio for doing this ?